# Restrict folder access for SSH users in freeSSHd

Tags: windows-7, ssh, freesshd

Is there any way to configure [freeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/) so that users who connect through SSH can only access a specific folder (+ all its contents), instead of being able to access all files?

I use on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.